# Updating MUI DataGrid when row data changes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

So im fetching data and passing to datagrid as a state but when a page change occurs it isnt updating unless another state change occurs(data is fetched correctly though).So for example i change the page data fetches but datagrid isnt updated,page is changed again now the data fetched previously is shown ,so its like always 1 step behind

```
const Transaction = () => {
  //searchbox input
  const search_text = useRef("");
  const [rows, setRows] = useState({ rows: [], count: 0 });
  const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isInvoicePopupOpen, setIsInvoicePopupOpen] = useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(null);
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState({
    id: "",
    DatePayed: "",
    DateIssued: "",
    Total: "",
    Project: "",
    Status: "",
    Client: "",
  });

  //pagination
  const [paginationModel, setPaginationModel] = useState({
    page: 0,
    pageSize: 5,
  });

  const params = useRef({
    limit: paginationModel.pageSize,
    page: paginationModel.page + 1,
    projectName: search_text ? search_text.current.value : "",
    status: options ? options.Status : null,
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    const getOptions = () => {
      const storedOptions = localStorage.getItem("transactionFilters");
      if (storedOptions) {
        setOptions(JSON.parse(storedOptions));
      }
    };
    getOptions();
  }, [isDrawerOpen]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cleanupLocalStorage = () => {
      localStorage.removeItem("transactionFilters");
    };
    // Cleanup localStorage on page refresh or exit
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", cleanupLocalStorage);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", cleanupLocalStorage);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    params.current = {
      limit: paginationModel.pageSize,
      page: paginationModel.page + 1,
      projectName: search_text ? search_text.current.value : "",
      status: options ? options.Status : null,
    };
    console.log(params);
  }, [paginationModel, options]);

  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(
    "transaction",
    params.current,
    paginationModel
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setRows(data.data);
    }
    console.log('changed data')
  }, [data]);
  //pass it as prop to datagrid
  const handlePaginationModelChange = (newModel) => {
    setPaginationModel(newModel);
  };
  // Function when a row is clicked
  const handleRowClick = (params, event, details) => {
    setSelectedRow(params.row);
  };

  //close invoice popup
  const handleCloseInvoicePopup = () => {
    setIsInvoicePopupOpen(false);
  };
  const handleEnter = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      params.current.projectName = search_text.current.value;
      setPaginationModel((prevPaginationModel) => ({
        ...prevPaginationModel,
        page: 0,
      }));
    }
  };
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setPaginationModel((prevPaginationModel) => ({
      ...prevPaginationModel,
      page: 0,
    }));
  };

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Container
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          height: "60vh",
        }}
      >
        <CircularProgress size={200} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  }
  if (!data) {
    return <div>No data available</div>;
  }

  const columnss = [
    ...columns,
    {
      field: "actions",
      headerName: "",
      headerClassName: "hideRightSeparator",
      sortable: false,
      width: 400,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <ActionColumn
          View={() => setIsInvoicePopupOpen(true)}
          Edit={() => setIsInvoicePopupOpen(true)}
          Delete={() => setIsInvoicePopupOpen(true)}
        />
      ),
    },
  ];
  console.log("reloaded component");

  return (
    <>
      <Stack spacing={2}>
        <SearchBox fct={handleEnter} ref={search_text} />
        <DataTable
          rows={rows.rows}
          columns={columnss}
          rowCount={rows.count}
          filters={filters}
          paginationModel={paginationModel}
          onPaginationModelChange={handlePaginationModelChange}
          onRowClick={handleRowClick}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          drawer={() => setIsDrawerOpen(true)}
        />
      </Stack>
      <InvoicePopup
        isOpen={isInvoicePopupOpen}
        onClose={handleCloseInvoicePopup}
        rowData={selectedRow}
      />
      <FilterForm
        filterss={filters}
        isOpen={isDrawerOpen}
        onClose={() => setIsDrawerOpen(false)}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Transaction;
```

This is the useFetch hook:

```
  

      import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const useFetch = (url,params,reload) => {
      const [data, setData] = useState(null);
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      const [error, setError] = useState(null);
      console.log(params);
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await 
       axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/"+url,{params});
            setData(response.data);
          } catch (error) {
            setError(error);
            console.log(error);
          } finally {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        };
        fetchData();
        console.log('fetched data')
      }, [url,reload]);
    
      return { data, loading, error };
    };

      export default useFetch;
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to share useful information such as what `useFetch` is. In general an example here shold be a [mre].

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, _specific_ question.